# KeyError in Python script used to generate Bash scripts

Tags: python, bash, awk, keyerror

I have a Python script called renaming.py that I want to use to generate many Bash scripts (over 500). The Python script looks like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#Script to make multiple Bash scripts based on a .txt file with names of files
#The .txt file contains names of files, one name per line
#The .txt file must be passed as an argument.

import os
import sys

script_tpl="""#!/bin/bash
#BSUB -J "renaming_{line}"
#BSUB -e /scratch/username/renaming_SNPs/renaming_{line}.err
#BSUB -o /scratch/username/renaming_SNPs/renaming_{line}.out
#BSUB -n 8
#BSUB -R "span[ptile=4]"
#BSUB -q normal
#BSUB -P DBCDOBZAK
#BSUB -W 168:00

cd /scratch/username/renaming_SNPs

awk '{sub(/.*/,$1 "_" $3,$2)} 1' {file}.gen > {file}.renamed.gen

"""

with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        line = line.strip(".gen")
        script = script_tpl.format(line=line)
        with open('renaming_{}.sh'.format(line), 'w') as output:
            output.write(script)
```

The .txt file I pass as an argument to this Python script looks like so:

```
chr10.10.merged.no_unwanted.formatted.gen
chr10.11.merged.no_unwanted.formatted.gen
chr10.12.merged.no_unwanted.formatted.gen
chr10.13.merged.no_unwanted.formatted.gen
chr10.14.merged.no_unwanted.formatted.gen
chr10.15.merged.no_unwanted.formatted.gen
etc
```

When I run the Python script, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "renaming.py", line 33, in <module>
    script = script_tpl.format(line=line)
KeyError: 'sub(/'
```

I am not entirely sure what is happening, but here is what I think

- Something is wrong with line 33 - not sure what is the problem. I have used very similar scripts like this one before. In this line 33, I am replacing all the {line} instances in script_tpl by the entries in the .txt file (this happens 500, once for each line of the .txt file).
- I am very confused by the KeyError. I am working on Linux HPC server (using a Mac laptop). I have managed to use this awk command with no problem when directly typing it into the terminal (as a Bash command). However, it seems that Python is maybe getting confused when I try and "print" it as a variable in the script..

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `.format` all `{ }` in your string will invoke string formatting. Since you used those chars in your awk command, you must escape them. To do that you double the `{{` and `}}`:

```
script_tpl="""#!/bin/bash
#BSUB -J "renaming_{line}"
#BSUB -e /scratch/username/renaming_SNPs/renaming_{line}.err
#BSUB -o /scratch/username/renaming_SNPs/renaming_{line}.out
#BSUB -n 8
#BSUB -R "span[ptile=4]"
#BSUB -q normal
#BSUB -P DBCDOBZAK
#BSUB -W 168:00

cd /scratch/username/renaming_SNPs

awk '{{sub(/.*/,$1 "_" $3,$2)}} 1' {line}.gen > {line}.renamed.gen

"""
```

Here are the [relevant docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Comment: This nearly works, no more KeyError but it doesn't replace {{file}}.gen > {{file}}.renamed.gen with the appropriate entry. But if remove the double {{}} I get the error again

Comment: @m93 if you want to replace {file} maybe you mean {line}?? There is no {file} variable. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `str.format` it will try to format everything inside `{}`s.

So this line is the problem:

```
awk '{sub(/.*/,$1 "_" $3,$2)} 1' {file}.gen > {file}.renamed.gen
```

Because the string formatter is trying to find the kwargs `sub(/` and `file` in your format call, which don't exist because the only key you specified is `line=line`.

If you don't want these to be considered for formatting you need to escape the braces.  (The format call should remove one of the pairs in the final string.)

```
awk '{{sub(/.*/,$1 "_" $3,$2)}} 1' {{file}}.gen > {{file}}.renamed.gen
```